# Hibernate OneToOne relationship needs child value to be passed from parent domain object

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have created the below OneToOne relationship with Hibernate and Kotlin. However, when I am Initializing `Parent()` it requires me to set `child` value as `Parent(child=null)` which is not desired. Only initializing child  should require parent as `Child(parent=Parent(...)` and if I add both parent to child and child to parent, it creates an infinite loop. What it the right way to avoid that?

```
    @Entity
    class Parent(
        @Id
        @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "uuid")
        val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
        @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], mappedBy = "parent")
        @JsonIgnore
        @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        val child: Child?
    )
    @Entity
    class Subscriber(
        @Id
        @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "uuid")
        val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
        @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id", columnDefinition = "uuid")
        @MapsId
        val parent: Parent
    )
```

Comment: As you are already using MapsId... I don't think you need to bi-directional mapping. In the child object you can have onetoone with parent with MapsId. It would be most efficient way of one to one over bi-directional.

Check the examples from hibernate master himself : https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: what part i need to remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As parent and child are mapped one to one and you want to use @MapsId to not create another extra PK in child table. Now Child object will use parent_id has its own PK.

For Parent

```
    @Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "uuid")
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Parent setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Child

```
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "uuid")
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private Parent parent;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Child setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public Child setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Check below screenshot for how table will look in database.
[image]